# HTML Canvas element not getting rendered post Formik form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, formik

In my React app, I have a Canvas element as a part of my Formik form. I let users chose and image from a selection of images which gets rendered on the canvas. My app also allows user to enter a short message which also gets rendered next to the image. When user submits the form by clicking a button, I want the Canvas to retain it's content though it's not happening. I get a blank canvas post form submission. Any idea how to keep the content on Canvas intact post form submission?

```
    const handleSubmit = (initialValues, { e, setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
    
        const canvasDataURL = canvasRef.current.toDataURL("image/png");
        var buffer = canvasDataURL.replace(
                    /^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/,
                     ""
                     );
        initialValues.card = buffer;

    

        API.post("/api/card-app/sendCard", initialValues, {
               signal: signal,
         })
      .then(function(response) {
        

        if (response.data.response==="Success") {
          setSnackbarSeverity("success");
          setSnackbarMsg("Your card has been sent successfully.");
          setSnackbarOpen(true);
          
          setSubmitting(false)
          setInitialValues(initialValues)
        } else {
          setSubmitting(false);
          setSnackbarSeverity("error");
          setSnackbarMsg(
            "Unable to send your card."
          );
          setSnackbarOpen(true);
          
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        setSubmitting(false);
        setSnackbarSeverity("error");
        setSnackbarMsg(
          "Unable to send your card. Please contact IT Service Desk for assistance."
        );
        setSnackbarOpen(true);
        setprogressIndicator(false);
        console.log("*** ERROR RESPONSE : ", error);
      });
    setTimeout(() => {
    }, 50);
  };
         <div>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                //enableReinitialize
              >
                {({
                  submitForm,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleChange,
                  isSubmitting,
                  isValid,
                  dirty,
                  touched,
                  values,
                  errors,
                }) => (
                  <Form>
                    <div>
                      <Grid
                        container
                        direction="row"
                      >
    
                             <Item
                                sx={{
                                  width: "105em",
                                  height: "65em",
                                  variant: "outlined",
                                  border: "solid",
                                  borderRadius: "15px",
                                }}
                              >
                                <canvas
                                  id="card"
                                  name="card"
                                  ref={canvasRef}
                                  width="100"
                                  height="100"
                                  sx={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
                                ></canvas>
                                <img
                                  id="image"
                                  ref={imgRef}
                                  src={cardImage}
                                  width="900"
                                  height="900"
                                  alt={imageFileName}
                                  style={{ display: "none" }}
                                />
                              </Item>
    <Button
                              variant="contained"
                              //color="green"
                              size="large"
                              //className={classes.buttonGreen}
                              startIcon={<EmailIcon />}
                              disabled={
                                !(isValid && touched && dirty) || isSubmitting
                              }
                              style={{ marginTop: "2.5em", marginLeft: "25em" }}
                              onClick={() => {
                                submitForm();
                              }}
                            >
                              Send Card
                            </Button>
     </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
```